# Cannot connect to host using discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Im trying to build a pretty simple bot. Essentially send a message that will be pre-defined by user input. But Im just testing it all out and trying to get my head around it.

We've built a Slack bot and it works beautifully. I seem to be having issues finding the best route to take just to send a simple pre-defiend message.

I've found a few tutorials and attach the code below for what I understand I should be doing. But it's just not connecting based off what the Error codes are saying. 'cannot connect to host discord app.com etc

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', description='A bot that posts raffles.')


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print('------')


@bot.command()
async def raffle(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Hello!")

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: Please edit your title to include something like 'cannot connect to host discord app.com', because that's the problem, not sending messages. Also, did you create a discord app that generated a token? Did you add your bot to a discord server?

Comment: Are you running your bot locally, or using a hosting service?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot connect to host you are most likely IP banned (or your server is), this could have meant that someone who previously used your IP did some stupid stuff. To get unbanned you should probably message support@discordapp.com

Also, have you tried to run the bot locally?